# Add LineFeed to command line option (windows 7)

Tags: command-line, cmd, linefeed

I have Problems adding a line feed in a string passed to a command line command. The Syntax is like this:

```
sometool --modifyfield "Description"="How to add a line feed?"
```

What I already tried without success:

```
sometool --modifyfield "Description"="How to add a \n line feed?"
sometool --modifyfield "Description"=$"How to add a \n line feed?"
... and othercombinations using % and ^
```

...but I always see exactly the text behin the "=" in my Description field.

Is it possible to add a line feed here?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell can be installed on Windows 7. Is `sometool` an executable .exe?

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "& sometool --modifyfield "Description"="How to add a `n line feed?"
```